Student is almost always late, and expects me to re-explain everything he missed
I teach introductory calculus to engineering students at my local college. I have one student who is consistently late for class. My class is at 8:20 in the morning, so I do have some sympathy for my students. After all, most 20-somethings aren't exactly morning people.
What bothers me though, is that this one student, whenever he is late (which is about 80 % of the time), comes down to me during the first break and expects me to privately explain to him everything he missed due to his tardiness. Since I do care about my students, I usually do this, but this also means that I really do not get any break time at all. And I am starting to get a little bit annoyed, without showing it of course, that this student, in a sense, asks for special treatment. I am slightly afraid that I might set the precedent that it is totally ok for my students to be late, as they can then always expect me to go over the material a second time during break time.
If anyone has any advice as to how I should deal with this situation, then I would greatly appreciate it!

What’s wrong with saying "no"? Have you asked them if they have a good reason for being late?

Thank you for your comment. I have not asked the student yet why he is late. Perhaps I should :). Also, I have not said "no" yet as I try to be a nice lecturer and offer my stduents help. However, this situation is new for me (constantly late student who exepcts me to go over the material again), and it is getting slighlty annoying. I know I will have this student next semester too, so that's why I think I should perhaps do something so that I do not have to deal with this for a whole schoolyear.

Next term, add to your syllabus, "If you miss a class or part of a class, it is your responsibility to get notes from a student who was present.  Often you'll get better notes if you make such arrangements in advance."  (A comment, not an answer, because it does not address the question asked.)

My answer would depend on the reason tat the student was late. A student who has poor time keeping would get a different answer to one who struggled because of caring responsibilities, such as them being delayed dropping children off.

I would not ask why they are late, because if they give a good answer, you've painted yourself into a corner.  They have a responsibility to be on time, and if they cannot manage that -- for whatever reason -- the consequences are squarely on them.

If it were me, I would feel that I need a short break in order to fulfil my duty to the whole cohort by giving my full attention to the second part of the class.  So I would tell the student that I will help them with anything they have missed or do not understand during my office hours outside class.  ...continued

An advantage of this is that you will soon find out whether they are a diligent student who has perhaps a good reason for being late, or whether they are simply being slack - the latter very likely indicated by their not turning up for your offered help.  If you are satisfied that they do deserve some "special" assistance, you can always change the arrangement and say that you will help during the break after all.

My teachers at college would never re-explain anything if someone was late. A few of them would not let you in if you were more than 10 minutes late. I think sharing lecture notes is good enough. The student's boss in the future won't restart the meeting or go through the discussed content again if he joins it late. He will likely get fired if he is late all the time. Better to learn soon than latter to be responsible.

Another comment says: "I would not ask why they are late, because if they give a good answer, you've painted yourself into a corner.". I disagree. You can ask the question, in order to help them finding a long-term solution –while being clear that re-explaining again and again is not a solution. You're not a social worker, and you may not be in a position to help them directly depending on the problem, but you still might have useful information they might have missed (e.g. you could direct them to support services provided by your college if they have some personal problems at home).

"Also, I have not said "no" yet as I try to be a nice lecturer and offer my students help." If students figure out that they can take advantage of your generosity and willingness to be nice, I predict that you'll have to deal with more of this and similar stuff in the future.

There’s a difference between being sympathetic and being taken advantage of. Aren’t you interested in improving the academic habits of your students? If you must persist, recommend the late-to-class student catches up on the material after class with another student.

I know it’s not easy, but the key is to tell them this:

No.

Give or take some pleasantries as per local culture. You can add some details, such as stating that you need a break now too, or that you expect students to follow the lecture.
Personally, I strongly recommend to avoid anything that amounts to a justification. You should not get into a discussion on whether it is proper, justified, or whatever that you spend your break on them.

That said, if you have a good relationship with your students, it can be worth to inquire if they have a justification for their behaviour. After all, it makes quite a difference to sacrifice your break for someone troubled by health or family issues versus someone just too lazy to bother being on time.

Thanks! I believe I will ask, in a polite manner, if there is a reason why the student is late. You arer right - it quite a different story if the student has issues with health/family versus if the tardiness is simply caused by the student being lazy. If the latter is the case, then I will try to encourage the student to be on time, and explain that I sometimes need my break time too.

@Kristian It might work differently in some cultures, but I would in general assume that if the student had a decent reason to be late, they would have shared it with you right away. "Sorry I was late since I had to drop off my child at the daycare which only opens at 8. Could you tell me what I missed?" If the student does this repeatedly and still doesn't feel like explaining, that IMHO strongly suggests they don't really have a decent reason and are just abusing your tolerance and kindness.

@TooTea: Thank you for your reply! I think I will ask him politely next time why he so often comes late to class. And if the reason simply is laziness, then perhaps gently explain to him that when you are a college student, you can not, as a general rule, expect lecturers to go over the material more than once.

@Kristian Perhaps even better to be less gentle and more blunt in telling him this behaviour isn't acceptable. If he shows up 20 minutes late for work every other day, many (most?) employers will not be happy at all; depending on locale this might even be enough for disciplinary action or termination. College is meant to prepare people for the professional world, which includes respecting basic rules of the workplace. Being way too kind and tolerant to a student can actually harm said student in the long run.

Thanks again. Yeah, I know it's a fine line, and I honestly like to help students! It just feels like much of the time I have to spend on this student could have been avoided had the student simply showed up on time. Sometimes he doesn't even ask a specific question, but just asks if I can review the material I covered at the beginning of class and the only reasons he gives is "because I was late". I might take a gentle approach first,, and then, if it does not help, ratch it up a little notch.

@Kristian As a downside, this can result in a negative evaluation from the student at the end of the semester. If you do care about this, it’s probably better to explain your reasons at the first occurrence.

It's an anecdote, but I nearly always slept in my Linear Algebra class.  One day, the professor (who had their own ideas of why I was sleeping) finally asked why I was sleeping.  I mentioned to him that my "day" started at 6 or 8 PM the night before, where I managed a grocery store, where I helped restock the shelves, reorder goods, etc, until about 6 AM, when I would then get on a bus because I didn't trust myself to drive in such a tired state, to drag into his class just before 7:30 AM (it was a rare, early class).  When he realized my schedule, his comment was "you can sleep in my class"

@Kristian "then perhaps gently explain to him that" I don't think if it is the case you need to be very gentle - a "I won't give a summary every time, if it is just for you, and just because you were late" is clear and polite enough. However, make sure they do not get the feeling that asking any question is bad. If you agree with this, perhaps you could state that specific questions are ok (and could actually even be asked during the lecture because other students probably also did not get it)

You need to have some kind of catch-up mechanism in place, as even the most diligent student might miss a lecture due to circumstances beyond their control. At my university, we record lectures. But sufficiently detailed lecture notes, or maybe just slides + pointers to specific sections in a textbook would also do. It should be clearly communicated to students how they are meant to catch up for missed lectures.
You could, in principle, have "come to me in the break or office hours and I explain it to you personally" as your catch-up mechanism, but that scales badly (and is probably a bad use of your time anyway). I will thus assume that this is not your designated catch-up mechanism.
With a proper catch-up mechanism in place, if a student asks you to recap the material they just missed, you can respond with eg "please go over the lecture notes for today, and then come back and ask any question you still have after that".

This answer gets to the heart of the matter. Let me add that producing lecture notes does not have to be a time-consuming process. Designating one of the students to be a note-taker (people will volunteer if there is a small amount of extra credit attached to it) and sharing their notes electronically after class has worked well for me in undergraduate math courses.

Thanks! I provide very detalied lecture notes and I make sure that they are pedagogical and easy to follow. I also do not mind if a student every now and then misses parts of my class, and then asks me to review the material he/she missed. The problem I am faced with now is that it is always the same student who is late, and this very same student always comes to be during break time and asks me to explaine to him the material he missed due to his tardiness. This happens at almost every lecture,

I would second this. I keep all of my handouts and material on my course website, and I video all of my lectures. If someone needs to catch up the just log on to my course page and view it. Since I started doing this starting this I've found that students tend to review the notes before coming to me with any problems much more often. This leads them to have much more thought out questions, and thus I'm able to give them much more thought out answers.

By accepting to reexplain during the break time, you are doing to the student and yourself a disservice. For the student, because he will get used to come late and that it has no consequence,  and to the fact that the world turns around him and then life will show that it is not the case. And for you, since you cannot do what you would like to do during the break : take a coffee, reply to some emails or simply relax, or whatever.
If the student misses some part for any reason, valid or not, he is supposed to catch-up by all the available means: notes of other students, online lecture notes for example. Then if after having reviewed the missed material he has questions, then you can answer them.
It is important to be able to say no without feeling that you have something to reproach to yourself (easy to say, not so easy to do). You work as a teacher is to reply to question, re-explain notions and so on during the classes and office hours but you do not owe the student anything during the break. Imagine the situation where a student comes late and misses the topics T1, T2 and T3, an other one only T1 and T2 and the third one only T1. A a fourth student missed the previous lecture and want you to do a summary. Would you spoil your break and more to re-do what you did in class?

If a student does not understand something in your lecture, it is absolutely a Good Thing that they try to make up for this. Whether this lack of understanding is due to them arriving late or not is not relevant at this point.
Imagine this was a student who arrived on time every single day... and still came to you in 80% of your breaks with questions. How would you feel in this situation? I think this thought experiment might clarify your reaction.
Calculus is hard. It is quite understandable that students do not understand everything. And it's better for them to try to work on that understanding as soon as possible, rather than finding out the hard way in the exam at the end of class that their understanding is deficient.
We can't tell you whether you "should" be fine with a student coming to you in 80% of your breaks. Some instructors are fine with having discussions in every single break. Other instructors need that time to recharge.
I personally would explain to your student that it's quite common not to understand everything at the first pass, and that it is good that they try to work on that. However, you also need your break. As such, the student's first step should be to go over the material after class, either alone or together with other students. If things are still unclear here, direct them to your office hours or any TAs.
At this point, and only now, I would add gently that you have the impression that they are sometimes late, and that their tardiness correlates with their questions. So they might try to make an effort to arrive on time, in case this is the root cause.
You need to judge whether it makes sense to go into the fact that not everyone will pass calculus. Some students simply do not have the mathematical aptitude. Others have personal situations that do not allow them to invest the necessary time, whether this is having to work late, or having to take public transport that makes them be late every single time. Either one is unfortunate, but you can only make up for problematic circumstances to a limited degree.

Thanks for your comment. There is clearly a correlation with the questions the student asks, and what he missed due to being late. Often, he would even start by saying "I arrived late today, so can you please just review from me what I missed?". I will ask the student, politely, if there is a reason for why he is late, and encourage him to be on time.

+1 it may be worth asking if there is an extenuating circumstance for their lateness - it may be something they can't do much about (e.g. caring responsibility).  Not neccessarilly easy to phrase the question, so could probably do with some thought beforehand.

Downvoted. Obviously it very much is relevant that the student repeteadly misses class and then asks the instructor to repeat what was said in class. An instructor has a responsibility to clarify questions that students have. However, this responsibility does not arise if the student does not do their part of bargain. In particular, they have no responsibility to repeat the highlights of their lecture for people who regularly miss class. Students cannot just unilaterally decide to offload their own learning work onto the instructor.

I don’t follow the thought experiment. If the same person comes to me in the breaks of 80% of lectures because they didn’t understand something important, at least one of us is doing it wrong. Supporting this bad behaviour – no matter on whose side – by sacrificing time allotted otherwise is at best a bandaid.

@MisterMiyagi: my point is exactly that the tardiness is not the key aspect here. The "coming to the instructor for one-on-one explanations 80% of the time" is the key problem. This would already be a problem if the student were on time every day, and the answer should be the exact same: some support is warranted, but this is an excessive demand on the part of the student. The tardiness "only" comes in as a root cause: if the student came in late but understood everything, it sounds like the OP would not have an issue.

... I believe that looking at things from this angle helps the OP understand where their real problem lies. It's not the tardiness, it's the excessive demand for one-on-one instruction. Which is precisely why I believe that addressing the tardiness is not the most important point here - addressing the student's feeling of entitlement is. (Quite obviously, a number of people disagree with me. That's fine. I stand by my opinion.)

@StephanKolassa Thanks for the clarification. I think that is just not clear at the moment for the answer as written. The "absolutely a Good Thing" opening makes (to me) all the leading paragraphs read like the specific behaviour is a good thing too. It’s not until the fifth paragraph that there is a clear but small hint that the answer considers the behaviour not absolutely a Good Thing.

I wouild be tempted to schedule the student to explain what they missed at 8:00 a.m. of the next day, i.e. just before the next class. Which means that in order to recover what he missed directly from the teacher, not only he will need to be on time for the next class but also perform an extra effort to arrive even earlier.

It is correct that you should not have to provide this extreme degree of accommodation. I am just making a supposition here, but based on my own lifetime experience having pretty serious and disruptive ADHD, I know that one of the primary ways this condition expresses itself in people with ADHD is what is called "Time Blindness". No, this is NOT a "get out of jail free" card. It is simply an incredibly well-researched by neuroscientists precept that communicates not only is this a serious problem zone for the person, but also in many way it is out of her or his control. To a point!
I am simply saying it is highly possible this student suffers from all sorts of processing lag cognitive problems, and task management executive functionsd such that it could be a serious struggle for them. As easy as it is for outsiders to be dismissive of, or disbelieving in, the level of control such an ADHD person has in relation to managing this real problem, it is in fact a very well-known facet of the disorder. (See neuroscience and ADHD expert Dr. Russell Barkley on this topic on his youtube channel, and/or expert sites from CHADD, ADDA, ADDitude Magazine, verywellmind).
NOTE: This answer will likely be too detailed and need editing, but I am writing it because I believe it is important.
Since ADHD is a recognized disability under the law, it is at minimal useful for people in yours and other professions to have some minimal knowledge of this. And it is very common that in educational/learning environments, such students are often provided some forms of accommodation to help the student.
My purpose in writing this however is to state that this kind of persistent or constant lateness, coupled with the student's expectation that you help "catch him or her up" is way out of scope for "reasonable accommodation". In this possible scenario I am presenting, the student would likely be aware that she or he has been diagnosed with ADHD, thus knowing or learning about this common executive function struggle. In which case an initial presentation of these problems showing up might lead to a student requesting some form of catch-up help. IF this were an initial problem showing up, and a teacher were to be informed of this, along with a request "could you please help me catch up?", I would consider that a reasonable request.  But as many many have stated, any kind of ongoing expectation of "catch up sessions because I was late" is completely out of bounds, and, again as many have stated, completely unsustainable for you with your workload and responsibilities. The corrected expectation, to me, would be "You've got to figure out a way to mitigate these lateness struggles. It will require work and effort by you, whether it means setting multiple alarms to ensure you wake up not just ON TIME but with additional padded time to account for unforeseen circumstances  (be they transportation hiccups, or behavioral breakdowns, whatever).
The flip side to the many uncontrollable, or hard to control, signal processing functions inherent to ADHD is that research also shows that ADHD people tend to have incredibly adaptive & creative mechanisms to problem solve for both the chronic lateness problem as well as the "how do I catch up on the material I missed due to lateness".
I like the answers and suggestions re having a "catch-up mechanism in place." In the end, I am (1) providing a possible context for the chronic lateness, while (2) also stating adamantly that the solution to this student's problem is not incumbent solely on you. My scenario here may not even be remotely at play with this student; could be something else entirely. Still, I would recommend at least having the conversation once with this student to ascertain "Do you know if ADHD is possibly behind this problem?" and if it is, empathy is a remarkable force multiplier in helping to talk over what he or she might be able to do to better regulate and accommodate their own problem. But beyond placing the issue on the table, and perhaps initially (early on!) accommodating the request for some catch up session, it should be made perfectly clear that as much as you may sympathize, it is the student's responsibility to mitigate this chronic problem.
Lastly I want to state that, again, as incredulous as it may seem to some people, you would be surprised just how many people exhibit the wide array of symptoms of the neurological disorder, yet have zero awareness that they possibly even have the disorder. One salient illustration. I got mostly straight-A's from grade school, high school, on through college. Yet because of my age and era of growing up, nobody in the 1960's and 70's were ever screened for ADHD because it was largely unknown except in the most esoteric of situations. Did I know I had problems with being late, with losing things all the time, forgetting things mid-sentence, having stressful breakdowns because too many noises, voices or other distractions would knock my thoughts and attention straight out of my head? Yeah, I knew it very well. But even with 45 years of different therapists & doctors, nobody ever, not in the 80's, not in the 90's, not in the 2000's, ever once pointed out "Has anyone ever told you you might have ADHD?". Only at age 63 did an ER doctor ever pose the question -- turns out yes I had it diagnosed, and no matter when it was diagnosed, you had the condition your entire life.

Footnote Links: https://www.reddit.com/r/AmItheAsshole/comments/y7j8cq/aita_for_sticking_to_the_late_policy_in_my_class/ | https://chadd.org/attention-article/time-unbound-managing-time-blindness-at-work/ | https://www.scottshapiromd.com/five-tips-to-help-people-with-adult-add-who-are-chronically-late/ | https://www.reddit.com/r/Teachers/comments/x2afbe/can_anyone_tell_me_why_adhd_kids_get_extra_time/ | https://www.reddit.com/r/ADHD/comments/33d96n/question_is_adhd_a_legitimate_reason_to_be_late/ | https://www.ed.gov/media/document/dcl-know-rights-201607-504pdf

I wouldn't ask the student "Is ADHD possibly behind this problem". If the student knows they have ADHD and they want accommodations for it, they should bring it up. It's inappropriate to guess at disabilities that students may have.

You always have the privilege to comment on your own posts. Please don’t use an answer for commenting on the answer itself.

I tried. The UI wouldn't let me. It kept displaying red error messages. Something about I couldn't use the @somebody because I'd made a comment before using it.  Stack Exchange is great; at same time it's a bit too militaristic for my taste. Minor scuffs should just be let go without all the scolding.

deee (trying again) You're absolutely right. I didn't fully think that part through. A key part of my answer was that there are many more people / students than one might ever imagine who do not know they have ADHD, because no one has yet diagnosed them as such. But that does not mean "oh then it's unlikely the person has it". Just the opposite. All I was trying to do is create some baseline awareness that chronic lateness is a huge ADHD red flag. MisterMiyagi's comment on the highest rated answer would probably be appropriate: "Have you asked them if they have a good reason for being late?"

Jesus, a downvote for my answer?  Why do people do that. This one ticks me off because NO ONE prior to my answer even raised the disability concern for ADHD. The downvoting is itself very ablist and absolutely anti- American Disabilities Act. The arrogance of neuro-typicals punishing and purposefully suppressing disability information.

Fuck this entire site and platform. fuck you miyagi for downvoting my useful answer because someone's chalk line bled over your neat crisp border. no wonder this whole site is losing marketshare. 2.2 rating on TRUST PILOT - Despised by thousands of devs on reddit for all of this authoritarianism, rudeness, and utter delight in downvoting and shitting on participants. i will show myself out now.
